# where can i find source code for libcrypto++?

Tags: c++, linker, crypto++

I am using libcrypto++ for aes encryption. I would like to add in my code the methods: EVP_CipherInit_ex(), EVP_CipherUpdate(), EVP_CipherFinal_ex(). Where can I find this source codes?

thx. appreciate

Comment: [http://www.openssl.org/source/](http://www.openssl.org/source/)

Comment: [Crypto++ website](http://www.cryptopp.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:
http://www.openssl.org/source/
The downloadable tar.gz on the page contains both header and source files for the most common cryptography algorithms, including EVP

However, I believe you are misunderstanding what static linking means, and how it is different from dynamic linking. Here is a decent article:
http://kb.iu.edu/data/akqn.html

You don't need to manually add the .cpp and .h files to your project, just include the .h where you need to use the methods and link to the .lib.

Despite my and commenters' suggestions, if you still wish to manually add the .cpp and .h files, here is where they are located within the archive I linked above:

```
crypto\evp\evp.h
crypto\evp\evp_*.c
```

Comment: where are the function i've mentioned situated? there are not all the .cpp and all the .h files. i am tryting to run my app without using licrypto++.a but i have the error: evp_chiperinit_ext() unitialized. I added evp.h and evp.cpp and i have error: voir* to char* ...what are the .cpp and .h that is hould include in my file in order to run the app?

Comment: You really want to just link into the library, not copy the specific code files. When you're compiling, do something like `g++ -L/path/to/openssl/lib -lcrypto++ -I/path/to/openssl/include`

Comment: i want to copy the methodss i need from the library. i don't want to link the libray. i don't want dependencies. i want to use this code in php. so i can't link a static library. i need to have pure c++ code with just .h and .cpp files that works. please give some ideas. thx

Comment: @sunset, I believe you have a misunderstanding of how linking works. If you link to a static library, the code from the lib gets added to your executable. No dependencies. You don't need to manually add the .cpp and .h files to your project.